# How do I map SysReq to a key on my MacBook keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mac, macbook

My Macbook laptop keyboard doesn't have a <kbd>SysReq</kbd> key. Can I change an existing key to act like <kbd>SysReq</kbd>?

Comment: I'm editing your question so it has something to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an easy task once you know how to do it.

1. Check the keycode of yours key. Run this program at terminal.

   ```
   xev
   ```
2. It will open a blank window, click on your key and then check the terminal output,
3. For example, when I press <kbd>k</kbd> the terminal shows me:

   ```
   KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,    
       root 0x286, subw 0x0, time 1577277172, (-63,525), root: (902,565),    
       state 0x10, keycode 45 (keysym 0x6b, k), same_screen YES,    
       XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6b) "k"    
       XFilterEvent returns: False
   ```

   From which I know the keycode for my <kbd>k</kbd> key is 45.
4. Change them as you like creating this file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.Xmodmap
   ```

   Its contents should look like this example:

   ```
   keycode  45 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
   ```
5. Then run (or reboot):

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```

Comment: The image above is broken now. Can you edit your answer to include the example as text instead of an image. Text is better anyway, more searchable.